# How do you calculate a 4-way mixed ANOVA (4 way SPANOVA) by hand in a spreadsheet?

Tags: repeated-measures, excel

I would like to include an interactive 4-way mixed ANOVA (4-way SPANOVA) in a google sheets document. Does anyone know how to calculate it by hand in a spreadsheet without the use of SPSS or R?

Comment: Does [this](http://www.real-statistics.com/two-way-anova/anova-more-than-two-factors/) help?

Comment: @Thomas, Thanks for the link, but I want to do a 4 factor repeated measures ANOVA, not a 4 factor ANOVA between independent groups. My understanding is mixed ANOVAs (Repeated measure ANOVAs between multiple factors) is much more complex. I don't know how to adapt what you gave me without help.

Comment: Yeah, sorry then I cannot help you, if you do not want to use a software. Otherwise, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPB3xrsFl4o) can maybe be helpful if you can adapt it to a 4 way ANOVA. Or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iErm-ksxguY). Good luck.